# hiberfil.sys and pagefile.sys... rebuilt on boot?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, pagefile, disk-image, hibernate

I need to take an image of a drive. I'm working from a bootable CD, so I have the option to decruft before taking the image. The Windows installation on the drive has both hyberfil.sys and pagefile.sys which I would rather not include in the image. If I delete these from the drive, will Windows recreate these files if necessary?

EDIT

The Windows installation on the drive in question was shut-down cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It would be a better idea to use imaging software intelligent enough not to grab these files in the first place. There are other directories that are similar superfluous.